# Show edited state of post after accepting suggested edit

Tags: discussion, feature-request, suggested-edits

Assume you have enough rep for editing privileges. Consider the following scenario (which has happened to me multiple times):

1. You open a new question, believing you might be able to answer.
2. The question or its code is poorly formatted, and this makes the question significantly harder to parse/understand/answer.
3. There is already a suggested edit. This suggested edit is wonderful: it fixes all of the formatting issues that you saw earlier, and you don't see any way for the edit to be improved. The edit would make the question easier to parse, so you want the edit to be applied *now*, since it will help you write your answer.
4. Therefore, you **approve** the edit.
5. You happen to be the first person to review the edit (there was no way you could have known this fact). Thus:

   - The edit will not be applied until someone else approves the edit. You have no idea how long that will take, and it could be many minutes.
   - The question remains in its poorly-formatted state, making it difficult for you to answer.
   - Even though you have full edit privileges, you can no longer edit the question yourself.
   - You cannot truly view the question in its improved formatting. You can click on the "edit" button again, but this shows you the diff, which is narrower than normal and has distracting green highlighting that is no longer relevant to you. The diff covers the content below it, so you can't look at it while drafting an answer.
6. You leave the question in frustration without writing the answer you had hoped to write.

Would it be possible for edit reviewers to see the question in its edited state after approving a suggested edit, similar to how the edit suggester would see the question?

Comment: Is a small improvement to the edit considered abuse of the system? I know we tend to discourage trivial edit _suggestions_, but if you have full edit privileges you won't be bothering anyone else with it. I've done that before to push a good edit through, and I didn't think I was being _abusive_.

Comment: @Don'tPanic Sure, I have also improved edits when I can easily find improvements to make, and that isn't abuse of the system. But sometimes the suggested edit is just that good, and I find myself spending too much effort trying to find a trivial improvement when I'd rather be answering the question.

Comment: TL;DR - **Approve and Edit** will accomplish what you're looking for

Comment: My feature request is not mentioned in the duplicate target or its answers. Thus, I'm nominating this for reopening.